# Is Broadway up on New Year's Eve and New Year's Day?

Tags: new-york-city, public-holidays

I am planning a week in NYC with the primary objectives of seeing several Broadway shows and being in Times Square at midnight on New Year's Eve.

Will Dec 31st and Jan 1st be a normal Tuesday and Wednesday for Broadway shows, or will they have noticeably reduced show schedules?

Comment: I'm surprised you're asking about this 11 months ahead.  I'd be very surprised that there will be any performances on New Years eve in any of the major theaters given their location.  But You can wait until July and check http://www.ticketmaster.com to see if the tickets are available. :)

Comment: I do in fact need to plan the trip now.  I'm hoping that someone knows what the standard practice is for Broadway shows on those holidays.

Comment: On December 31st most streets adjacent to Times Square which house a lot of theaters are closed off, starting from 10am in some parts, for New Years Eve Ball Drop.  That makes getting to and from them next to impossible, so you will still need to wait until July to get your Dec/Jan tickets and see the schedules. :)  http://www.timessquarenyc.org/events/new-years-eve/nye-faq/index.aspx#13

Answer (score 4):

I got a partial answer from the [TKTS booth](http://www.tdf.org/TDF_ServicePage.aspx?id=56) folk:

> There are no Broadway shows on New Year's Eve.   Some off-Broadway
>   shows will play if out of the Times Square district.  Also, the tkts
>   booth has to close around 3PM on New Years Eve.

Comment: Just to clarify, what's TKTS? A website?

Comment: Ah, a discount booth. Updated your answer with a link to their site.